# Flink async IO operator chaining with with another sync operator

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a usecase where I am using async IO operators with normal mappers in flink. I am using flink 1.8. So, async operator is going to have to be at the head of the operator chain. So my operator flows looks like this:

Source -> Mapper1 -> AsyncOperator -> Mapper2 -> Sink

Because of the requirement of async operator being head, there are two operator chains and hence two tasks- 1. Source + Mapper1 2. AsyncOperator+Mapper2+Sink.
I have question regarding the second chain. I think the second chain should be comprised within a single task if they are chained correctly.  I am not sure if there is a wait time between async operator and mapper 2 on the task threads or the Mapper2 gets bound to the response handler for the Async Operator internally ? Ideally, it should be second, but I can't find any documentation for the same - hence wondering.

Reference:

1. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AsyncWaitOperator` spins up an `Emitter` in a thread, so as soon as results are available they get sent to the operator's collector. Note though that if you specify ordered results there can be a "wait time" due to completion order not matching the order of incoming elements.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, the restriction that the AsyncWaitOperator must be at the head of a chain was removed in Flink 1.11. See [FLINK-16219](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-16219). The only remaining limitation was that it could not follow a SourceFunction. The AsyncWaitOperator can follow the new sources introduced in Flink 1.12.