# Flink message retries like Storm

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to build a Flink job that would read data from a Kafka source do a bunch of processing including few REST calls and then finally sink into another Kafka topic.

The problem I trying to address is that of message retries. What if there are transient errors in the REST API? How can I do exponential backoff-based retry of these messages like the way Storm supports?

I have 2 approaches that I could think off

1. Use TimerService but then in case of failures the state will start to expand uncontrollably.
2. Write failed message to a different Kafka topic and process them with a delay of sorts, but here the problem can arise if the Sink itself is down for few minutes?

Is there a better more robust and simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: For approach #2, is your Kafka cluster down so often that simply relying on Flink to fail if the sink is down and then restart from a checkpoint isn't good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Flink's [AsyncFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html) to make the REST calls. If needed, it will backpressure the source(s) rather than use more than a configured amount of state. For retries, see [AsyncFunction retries](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/AsyncFunction-retries-td36505.html).

Comment: Thanks, but then I would have to give up on consistency correct? For practical reasons can't make the REST API the first call in the chain.

Comment: AsyncFunction works better for doing lookups than for making updates to external systems. It offers at-least-once guarantees.

Comment: as per the documentation AsyncIO can only be used at the head of the operator chain. Which I understand means that it has to be the first operator on the source stream, correct?

Comment: That restriction no longer holds; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66705952/2000823. But no, it never meant that it had to be the first operator in the job, but rather that it had to be the first operator in its task.